# GDAL configuration for Django in mac GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH exception

Tags: python, django, postgresql, geospatial, gdal

I tried to install GDAL in macos by the command for django `brew install django` and it successfully installed and I have also used `pip install GDAL` command and it also installed successfully.

But, When I tried to run the django server it throw a error set a path for GDAL library.

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal", "GDAL", "gdal3.2.0", "gdal3.1.0", "gdal3.0.0", "gdal2.4.0", "gdal2.3.0", "gdal2.2.0", "gdal2.1.0", "gdal2.0.0"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.
```

Answer (score 2):

I checked the 'gdal' and 'goes' library versions,

```
brew info gdal
brew info geos
```

And afterward, I put the two lines into my setting.py

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gdal/3.3.2_3/lib/libgdal.dylib"
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/geos/3.9.1/lib/libgeos_c.dylib"
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Those packages come with package config binaries.

Set these environment in the shell and than run your django specific commands.

```bash
export GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH="$(gdal-config --prefix)/lib/libgdal.dylib"
export GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH="$(geos-config --prefix)/lib/libgeos_c.dylib"
```